# Elasticsearch 6.7 - How to filter a nested array field that must contain given array items

Tags: filter, nested, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to filter search results by a field which is in a nested array object in elasticsearch (version 6.7.1).

Specifically trying to only return results that contain all terms in filter for a single field (typically this would be stored as an array of objects), in elasticsearch this has been stored as a nested type, see data structure below.

Mappings:

```
{
  ...
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        ...
        "dimensions": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            ...
            "name": {
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "analyzer": "raw_analyzer",
                  "type": "text",
                  "index_options": "docs",
                  "norms": false
                }
              },
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example documents:

Doc 1:

```
{
  ...
  "dimensions" : [
    {
      "label" : "time",
      "name" : "time"
    },
    {
      "label" : "geography",
      "name" : "geography"
    },
    {
      "label" : "statistics",
      "name" : "statistics"
    }
  ]
}
```

Doc 2:

```
{
  ...
  "dimensions" : [
    {
      "label" : "time",
      "name" : "time"
    },
    {
      "label" : "geography",
      "name" : "geography"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Age groups",
      "name" : "agegroups"
    }
  ]
}
```

Query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dimensions",
            "query": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "dimensions.name": [
                    "time",
                    "statistics"
                  ],
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query returns both docs 1 and 2 due to successfully matching at least one filter term in the `dimensions.name`.

What I would like to achieve is to only return doc 1 as it matches all terms. The logic is that if 1 or more filter terms for the `dimensions.name` field is missing to NOT return the document.

I have tried many variations of the above query using `minimum_should_match`, `execution` but I believe these were for older versions of elasticsearch.

Also I am wondering whether I should be modelling the data in a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the same by making a `must` query instead `filter`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dimensions",
            "query": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "dimensions.name": "time"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dimensions",
            "query": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "dimensions.name": "statistics"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As per the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html), you are matching for a term, so it should be part of query context. So `must` do the job for `query context`.

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs for your response, this worked but the must clause effected the score of the results. To get round this I just switched out must for filter and it worked perfectly due to having the correct structure under the filter field.

So to clarify the solution for me was to create an array of filters with multiple nested object queries for each term to filter by. So the exact same structure as Gibbs answer above but switching out must for filter.